# How to make and customize sections within the bars of a barplot created with ggpplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I have a data frame structured like `data` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Loc = paste("Loc", seq(1:20), sep = ""),
                   A = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5)),
                   B = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5)),
                   C = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5))
                   )
data$D <- 100-(data[,2]+data[,3]+data[,4])
data$total <- sample(c(10:20), replace = T, length(data[,1]))
```

Here, `Loc` is a grouping variable with 20 levels. Each `Loc` represents a locations from which samples were taken (the actual "samples" are not here). `A`, `B`, and `C` and `D` represent clusters that observations were assigned to. The associated values for each `Loc` that are in the columns `A`, `B`, and `C` and `D` represent the percentage of observations from each `Loc` that were assigned to each cluster. The `total` column represents the total number of observations that were taken from each `Loc`. For instance, there were 14 observations for `Loc1` 25% of those observations were assigned to cluster `B`, and 75% were assigned to cluster `D`.
I have made a bar plot that shows `Loc` on the x-axis and `total` on the y-axis. Assuming each cluster will be given a unique "color", I am trying to color the bars in such a way that for a given `Loc` the colors will represent the percentage of observations that were assigned to each cluster. For instance, say cluster `B` is yellow and cluster `D` is blue, then the bar for `Loc1` will be 25% yellow and 75% blue.
I have tried several variants of this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data%>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Loc,total), names_to= "Group", values_to = "val")%>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Loc, y=total, col = Group))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = val))+
  geom_text(aes(label = total))
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Which is close, but not what I want. How can I make this kind of plot? if possible, I would also like to move the value for `total` to the top of each bar, and the percentage associated with each respective color to be in the center of that "color" or "cluster's" section within each bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I added a variable with the numbers by group.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Loc = paste("Loc", seq(1:20), sep = ""),
                   A = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5)),
                   B = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5)),
                   C = sample(c(0,15,20,25,40),size = 20,replace = T, prob = c(45,25,15,10,5))
)
data$D <- 100-(data[,2]+data[,3]+data[,4])
data$total <- sample(c(10:20), replace = T, length(data[,1]))

data1 <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Loc,total), names_to= "Group", values_to = "val") %>%
  # Number per Group
  mutate(val1 = val * total / 100) 

data1 %>%
  # Map val1 on y, Group on fill
  ggplot(., aes(x=Loc, y=val1, fill = Group))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  # Make label only for the first group. Here: A
  geom_text(aes(y = total, label = ifelse(Group == "A", total, "")), nudge_y = 1, size = 3) +
  # Add percentages
  geom_text(aes(y = val1, 
                label = ifelse(val > 0, scales::percent(val, scale = 1, accuracy = 1), "")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I am unfamiliar with a few of these arguments, but I am working through it. could you explain what I can do in a situation where the percentages are small (e.g., 3%) or when there is overlap? When applying this to my real data set, some of the percentages overlap one another

Comment: Ahh I see the `position_stack()` argument can be adjusted to help with this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
#Format Loc
data$Loc <- factor(data$Loc,levels = paste0('Loc',1:dim(data)[1]),ordered = T)
#Melt
df <- melt(data,id.vars = c('Loc','total'))
#Create label
df$Label <- ifelse(df$value==0,NA,paste0(df$value,'%'))
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=Loc,y=value,color=variable,group=variable,label=Label,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color='black')+
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = data, 
            aes(x = Loc, y = 100, label = total), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, I would however like to retain the property of different bar heights to illustrate the number of samples in each group (the height being based on `total`) would you be able to adapt this code to accomplish that?

Comment: @Ryan Just a moment!